# FOR row IN SELECT (Postgres vs. MySQL)

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have already been doing some function in postgresDB, but im completly new to MySQL. I thought that it will be almost same to create procedure in MySQL, but aparently it is not. So I am asking for some help :)

In postgres I would write this function for what I need to accomplish:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS report_incomes;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION reportincomes(IN interval INT)

RETURN report_tab TABLE
    (
    year_month DATE,
    total DECIMAL(30,2),
    total_before DECIMAL(30,2)
    )
AS

BEGIN

    FOR row_d IN SELECT * FROM intervals_generator('2013-01-01 00:00:00', now(), interval) LOOP

        SELECT sum(cash) AS total, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%b %Y') AS year_month FROM incomes WHERE datetime BETWEEN row_d.start_d AND row_d.end_d//

        SELECT sum(cash) AS total_before FROM incomes WHERE datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(row_d.start_d, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND DATE_SUB(row_d.end_d, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)//

   END LOOP//

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

As you may noticed, the big part of code is already switched to MySQL, but I am kind of stuck with FOR LOOP, as it looks so different in MySQL compared to Postgres.

Of course there will be much more code added inside the LOOP, I just did not wanted to make it too complicated for explanation.

Could please anyone help me with the FOR LOOP?

Basicly, I want to execute these SELECTs for each row returned by function that generates my custom intervals, while using data from that row inside of LOOP

Comment: It would help if you described what you want to do in terms of data rather than Postgres code.  From what you seem to be doing, you might need a cursor.

Comment: I would like to get in one row, summary data for month next to summary data for same month from year ago.

Also there are other columns with partial data (sums by branch stores), but I don't have problem to get those. The problem I have is to add column with "same month from year ago" into table where I have branch sums, total sum, expenses and yield.

I have edited Question with this info.

Comment: Since it somehow does not let me edit my question, I am adding expected output info here.

**This should be my output:**

`| month| total_sum| branch_1_sum| branch_2_sum| branch_3_sum| expenses| yeld| total_sum_same_month_year_ago|`

If data in row are for example from April 2014, than last column "total_sum_same_month_year_ago" should be total sum of April 2013.